# Как заменить стандартную иконку выпадающего списка Autocomplete , другую иконку из mui?

Tags: reactjs, svg, typescript, autocomplete, mui

Проект пишу на typescript mui react.

Проблема в том, что renderToggle выдает ошибку

```
<Autocomplete
        {...props}
        PaperComponent={({ children }) => (
          <Paper >{children}</Paper>
        )}
        disabled={props.disabled || props.readOnly}
        disableClearable={false as any}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        ref={ref}
        renderInput={(inputProps) =>
            <TextField
              {...inputProps}
              readOnly={props.readOnly}
              label={props.label}
              error={props.error}
              helperText={props.helperText ?? " "}
              required={props.required}
              onFocus={handleFocus}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
         }
      />
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mui+react+Autocomplete+icon+site:stackoverflow.com